# Issues with properties file in IntelliJ (adding to classpath) JSP (null pointer ex)

Tags: java, jsp, properties, intellij-idea

I keep getting a null pointer exception when trying to load my properties file. This is my first time attempting to do this, and in my research it seems I need to add it to the classpath. Here is the code I am currently using to load it in:

```
    //Set up the properties
    String filePath = "src/prop.properties";
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath);

    //Load the properties file
    try
    {
        properties.load(inputStream);
        logger.info("Properties file was loaded successfully.");
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        logger.severe("Properties file could not be loaded. Exception : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ex)
    {
        logger.severe("Null Pointer exception occurred when attempting to load Properties file. Exception : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

To test out a properties file, I just right clicked on the my project and did New -- > File --> prop.properties

[image]

And I do not see it here (I may be looking in the complete wrong spot, honestly I am not sure) :

[image]

If I am understanding things correctly, shouldn't my prop.properties file be showing up under the src folder? Any help on how to accomplish this would greatly be appreciated, I have looked at other similar posts to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are placing your properties file into the `src` (a source code folder), it means the classpath root package. So you should access the file by the `getResourceAsStream("/prop.properties")`.

Comment: That was all it took! HUGE thanks, this trivial thing had me banging my head on the wall. Sometimes all you need is another set of eyes, I guess.